# How to compile a java program which implements package from command prompt

Tags: java

I have a folder names "projects" in c drive. i store all my java files in that folder.

my class path is : `c\projects`

Now i created a java file as myProgram in projects folder. in that file or program i created a package whose name is myPackage using the simple syntax

```
package myPackage;
```

at the very top of the program.

when i compile this program on the command prompt using following commands

```
c:\projects > javac myPackage.myProgram.java
```

i am getting the error

```
error: cannot read: myPackage.myProgram.java 1 error
```

please help

Comment: Your question is not about runnning a java program, it is about compiling one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the file in a folder thats named like the package.

Like this:

```
C:\
C:\projects\
C:\projects\myPackage\
C:\projects\myPackage\myProgram.java
```

Also note that usually `classes` start with an uppercase letter. So your class (and the File) should be named `MyProgram`.

Then you have to run the `javac` as Satheesh Cheveri correctly said from

C:\projects\

as

javac myPackage/myProgram.java

(note the `/` instead of `.` in the `javac` command).

Answer (score 1):

```
javac myPackage/myProgram.java
```